# JavaScript function to be create to calculate Price based on some info (example - store offers)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `[2,5,1]`$ which is prices, Customer pays `2`$ for the first item because no discount for first item, 
`5-2 = 3` for the second item,
`min(1st item, 2nd item) min(2,5) = 2` for 3rd Item; but if next item is lesser in cost compared to second item e.g. 1 is less 2 the cost will be zero;

```
so 2+3+0 is output of calculate price.
```

If i have one more input

```
[2,5,1,6]
2 + (5-2) + 0 + (6 - min(2,5,1))
```

How I can achieve this -

I was trying to write something like this -

```
function calculateAmount(prices) {
    // Write your code here
    var totalCostPurchase;
    var cost = [];
    var zero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            cost.push(prices[i]);    
        } else if (i === 1) {
            cost.push(prices[i] - cost[i - 1]);
        } else {
            var minCost = Math.min(...prices.slice(0,i));
            console.log(minCost);
            if (minCost > prices[i]) {
                cost.push(zero);
            } else {
                cost.push(prices[i] - minCost);
            }
        } 
    }
    totalCostPurchase = cost.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    console.log(totalCostPurchase);
    return totalCostPurchase;
}

Please guide.
```

Comment: Please write the formula. Why the 3th item is `0`, it should be `1` (`2 - 1`), no?

Comment: Agreed-- a clearer understanding of what the input data represents and your requirements would probably help you get a meaningful answer more quickly.

Comment: Will the array size increase? If you've some pattern over calculation of every item, you can write recursive function and will be easier to understand.

Comment: yes, array size will increae, my function works for upto 4 but not working for 10 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` for this

```js
var a = [2,5,1,6]

let res = a.map((d,i) => i != 0 
              ? d - Math.min(...a.slice(0, i+1))
              : d)
           .reduce((x, y) => x + y)
             

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Nice. However, this has *O(n^2)* time complexity.

Comment: Hi @slider. Nice to e meet you again.. No it does not have O(n^2).. Its rather O(2n) .... no ?

Comment: It's clearly *O(n^2)* because you compute the minimum using `Math.min(...a.slice(0, i+1))` for each element.

Comment: hmmm.. i see but i think it's less than n^2, i am not sure how to calculate it exactly.. neverthless if array length is not in hundreds/thousands then difference is hardly noticeble :) Btw good point @slider It's a good learning experience answering with you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) where the accumulator keeps track of the sum and min and updates based on your rules:

```js
function total(prices) {
  return prices.reduce(([sum, min], p, i) => {
    if (i === 0) return [p, p];
    let newSum = sum;
    if (p >= min) newSum += p - min;
    return [newSum, Math.min(p, min)];
  }, [])[0];
}


console.log(total([2, 5, 1]));
console.log(total([2, 5, 1, 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer, And this seems to work for all the cases, this may not be best solution but this is what i think through.

```
function calculateAmount(prices) {
    // Write your code here
    var totalCostPurchase;
    var cost = [];
    var zero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            cost.push(prices[i]); 
        } else if (i === 1) {
            if ((prices[i] - cost[i - 1]) < 0) { 
                cost.push(zero);
            } else {
                cost.push(prices[i] - cost[i - 1]);
            }
        } else {
            var minCost = Math.min(...prices.slice(0,i));
            if (minCost > prices[i]) {
                cost.push(zero);
            } else {
                if ((prices[i] - minCost) < 0) {
                    cost.push(zero);
                } else {
                    cost.push(prices[i] - minCost);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    totalCostPurchase = cost.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return totalCostPurchase;
}
```

Comment: I will try to reduce the code and will try to clean up.